# Two prompt lines using emacs shell and plink

Tags: shell, ssh, prompt

I am using emacs `M-x shell` command to create a shell, and from this shell I connect to a remote machine by using `plink` (PuTTY on windows).

I have a problem with the prompt being presented twice. I have `comint-prompt-read-only` set to *true*, such that the *yellow* prompt is uneditable. The blue prompt line behaves as if part of the output of the command. Also, `comint-process-echoes` is also set to *true*.

How can I get rid of this blue prompt and make my shell nice and clean looking without any extra lines? :)

I have looked at some of the similar questions to this, and many of them talk about the `$PS1` variable. I have changed this variable to be what you see. Other than that, there seems to be no good suggestions about this particular issue I am facing.

Does anyone have some helpful insight into what is causing this and how I can remove the extra prompt? Thanks in advance!

[image: Double prompt]

**EDIT (reproduction of issue)**

Downloaded a new emacs (v26.3 x86_64) from the official website (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Placed it aside from my main emacs configuration such that nothing but the standard configuration of emacs is used.

The session I use with PuTTY is all standard settings. It uses a private and public SSH key to verify the connection. Pageant is on to avoid having to put in the password for the SSH private key.

On the host machine, the `.bashrc` contains `PS1="[\u@\h:\w] $ "`.

The problem still persists as can be seen. Now the command is also echoed, but this is due to the fact that `comint-process-echoes` is set to `nil`.

[image]

**EDIT (with test of unset PROMPT_COMMAND)**
From the comment by @jpkotta, tried with `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` (and `unset $PROMPT_COMMAND`). However this does not seem to do the thing. I have a feeling it is something to do with emacs and not the remote machine..

[image]

Comment: Please post a minimal Emacs and shell configuration that reproduces the problem. Maybe it's related to some Emacs setting other than `comint-prompt-read-only`. Maybe it's related to some shell setting other than `PS1`. It may well be related to what's _in_ `PS1`, so you definitely need to post that.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question with a bit more info :)

Comment: Here's a guess: there's a PROMPT_COMMAND (bash variable) that is trying to set the terminal title or similar and Emacs is not interpreting its output correctly (the output is usually some terminal escape codes).  Try `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` and see if the issue persists.

Comment: To add to my comment, I set PROMPT_COMMAND in my .bashrc only if the TERM (env var) supports it.  Emacs shell TERM is `dumb`, which does not support any terminal escape codes AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks @jpkotta ! Tried it but it didn't work :( Edited the question with the update.

Comment: @Runei I agree it's probably something in Emacs then.  As a workaround, you can try `term-mode`, but that also might be weird.